# Javascript pause and resume transition animation on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to pause/resume transition animation on text. I have try so many solution for the similiar question, but still not succeed.

I want to pause the 'color effect' when click pause button, and when I click resume button the 'color effect' will finish the job coloring the whole text based on the rest duration.

Here's my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#start').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text('Resume');
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);

    $('span').addClass('active');
    $('span').dequeue();
  });
  $("#stop").click(function() {
    $('#start').attr('disabled',false);

    $('#start').clearQueue();
      $("span").stop();

      /*
    * it similiar like below,
    * but still not perfect.
    * when the duration of background-position-x has finished,
    * the transition start again. and yet still not perfect
      */
      /*$('span').animate({
      'background-position-x': '10%',
      'background-position-y': '20%'
    }, 10000, 'linear');*/
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
 }
 span {
     height: 25px;
     background-size: 200% 100%;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, transparent 50%);
     text-indent: 28px;
     font-size: 30px;
     background-size: 200% 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 100% top, 100% top;
     -webkit-background-clip: text, border-box;
     background-clip: text, border-box;
     color: transparent;
 }
 .active {
  background-position: 0% top, 0% top;
     transition: background-position 10s; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Pause</button>
```

note : I know there is so many 'javascript pause/resume' question, I already try to implement with my case, but still not succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Jquery to toggle the css `animation-play-state`

Ensure you add prefixes to your animation properties for cross browser compatibility (-moz,-webkit, etc)

Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text('Resume');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    $('span').addClass('active');
    $('span').dequeue();
  });
  $("#stop").click(function() {
    $('#start').attr('disabled', false);

    $('#start').clearQueue();
    $('span').removeClass('active');
    $('span').addClass('stop');
    $("span").stop();

    /*
     * it similiar like below,
     * but still not perfect.
     * when the duration of background-position-x has finished,
     * the transition start again. and yet still not perfect
     */
    /*$('span').animate({
      'background-position-x': '10%',
      'background-position-y': '20%'
    }, 10000, 'linear');*/
  });
})
$("span").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function() {
  $("#start").attr('disabled', false);
})
```

```css
@keyframes anime {
  from {
    background-position: auto
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0% top, 0% top;
  }
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

span {
  height: 25px;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, transparent 50%);
  text-indent: 28px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% top, 100% top;
  -webkit-background-clip: text, border-box;
  background-clip: text, border-box;
  color: transparent;
}

.active {
  animation: anime 10s;
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}

.stop {

  animation: anime 10s;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Wow excellent..! Thank you very much... I used animation-play-state on the other solution, but not work. Now I know how to use it. Thank you so much.